# OSGI: is it possible to import a bundle only if it exists externally, otherwise use a local cut-down version?

Tags: osgi

The problem I am facing is that an application is being deployed on an OSGi container that is maintained by a third party.

There is some functionality in my bundle that imports external packages which may or may not be available. For the case when the bundles are not available a client bundle exists inside my bundle (to help avoid ClassNotFound exceptions). In the other case, when the bundles exist, the packages should be imported.

Is this possible somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Situation

Let me see if I understand the question correctly: suppose we are talking about some package `foo`. If someone in your environment exports this package, you want to import exactly that package.

```
[someone-else] --exp--> foo <--imp-- [you]
```

If noone exports the package, you have copy of it yourself, in what you call a 'client bundle'; I don't really understand what you mean by that, but I guess it means that you want to export some packages conditionally, so we end up in the situation

```
[you] --exp--> foo
   |            ^
   |            |
   -----imp------
```

So, you get wired to yourself.

I also gather that you have tried exporting the `foo` package yourself, but finding that when you do, you can not communicate with other bundles using classes from the `foo` package.

### Solution

If the situation above is correct, you can use default OSGi behavior. You declare that you *both* export and import a package,

```
Export-Package: foo
Import-Package: foo
```

You will now *always* export the package, but the OSGi resolving mechanism will make sure the wiring happens correctly:

- If someone already exports `foo`, you will get wired to that existing package, and your own export will be 'ignored' for now', and
- if you're the only one exporting it, you will get wired to yourself.

In both situations, you get wired to the same package everyone else is using, what is exactly what you need.

In short, you shouldn't worry about this situation too much, and in general *always import what you export*. Most tools ([bnd](http://www.aqute.biz/Code/Bnd), the [Apache Felix maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html)) will actually do this for you. If you're writing your manifests by hand, you should look into these to make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

In my view it is not possible. You can only choose one solution:

1. You add the external packages to your bundle (That is not the OSGi way). But than your bundle runs on every OSGi  container (framework).
2. You must make shure that on the OSGi container (framework) the bundles with your needed packages are installed. The dependencies of your bundle normally must be entered in the manifest file and than the dependencies **must** be avaiable.

**You must decide!**

Comment: I've been reading up on dynamic imports. Is there no chance this *might* work? What are the priorities for finding where to source the packages from?

Comment: If you declare the needed packages in the bundle manifest, the OSGi framework try to find that packages in it's framework. You must not specify in which bundle that package is declared. That is the default way. To make sure hat your needed packages are available you must add the needed packages to the classpath. I didn't heard about dynamic imports in the OSGi context! Can you post where you read about it? Or did you mean dynamic services???