# Calling session.getWorkspace().getQuery() causes errors

Tags: java, osgi, jackrabbit, jcr, sling

I'm implementing an osgi bundle containing a search service (AbstractService). 
This service contains a method to get a list of content nodes as a NodeIterator object.

```
 public NodeIterator getNodes(Session session, String query, long count) throws RepositoryException{
            NodeIterator nodeIterator = null;

            QueryManager queryManager = session.getWorkspace().getQueryManager();

            Query qry = queryManager.createQuery(query, Query.SQL);
            qry.setLimit(count);
            QueryResult result = qry.execute();
            nodeIterator = result.getNodes();


        return nodeIterator;
    }
```

I have the an error on line:

```
QueryManager queryManager = session.getWorkspace().getQueryManager();
```

error

```
org.apache.sling.api.SlingException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /apps/IMEApp/Content/Category/../../General/html_marketCommentary.jsp at line 49
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspExceptionInternal(JspServletWrapper.java:571)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:496)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:442)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspServletWrapperAdapter.service(JspServletWrapperAdapter.java:59)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:173)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:84)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:388)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:358)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:170)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:456)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:529)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:274)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:161)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:183)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:96)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:42)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:48)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:39)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.jcr.Workspace.getQueryManager()Ljavax/jcr/query/QueryManager;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/felix/framework/ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoaderJava5) of the current class, org/dapa/ime/service/AbstractService, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/felix/framework/ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoaderJava5) for resolved class, javax/jcr/Workspace, have different Class objects for the type javax/jcr/query/QueryManager used in the signature
    at org.dapa.ime.service.AbstractService.getNodes(AbstractService.java:43)
    at org.dapa.ime.service.NewsService.getListOfNews(NewsService.java:35)
    at org.dapa.ime.service.NewsService.getListOfTopNews(NewsService.java:57)
    at org.apache.jsp.apps.IMEApp.Content.Category.html_jsp._jspService(html_jsp.java:1995)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    ... 37 more
```

I can't understand caused by section:

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.jcr.Workspace.getQueryManager()Ljavax/jcr/query/QueryManager;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/felix/framework/ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoaderJava5) of the current class, org/dapa/ime/service/AbstractService, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/felix/framework/ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoaderJava5) for resolved class, javax/jcr/Workspace, have different Class objects for the type javax/jcr/query/QueryManager used in the signature
```

Could any body help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

### What?

A `LinkageError` of this kind is often caused by incomplete OSGi metadata: in the current situation, you have allowed two bundles (the one loading `AbstractService` and the one loading `Workspace`) to have different version of `QueryManager`.

### And now?

You have too many copies of this `QueryManager` in your system, and you need to either get rid of all but one, or make sure the correct one gets picked. The first one is most likely, the second one is only likely to occur if you have built your bundles by hand.

#### One `QueryManager` to rule them all

Check whether multiple bundles contain this class. I don't know how you build you bundles, but you probably have some overly ambitious tool putting the class into every bundle that needs it. A common cause of this is using `<Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>` in your Maven POM.

Have one bundle provide this class, and have it export ([and import!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818967/osgi-is-it-possible-to-import-a-bundle-only-if-it-exists-externally-otherwise)) the packge.

#### Pick the right one

If you do have multiple copies for a good reason, make sure all bundles agree on which one to use. Make sure that,

- when a bundle exports the `javax.jcr.query` package, it also imports it, so the resolver can pick one it deems most useful, and optionally
- be explicit about the copy of `javax.jcr.query` that must be used when some bundle uses `javax.jcr.query`. You can do this by placing a [`uses` constraint](http://njbartlett.name/2011/02/09/uses-constraints.html) on your export, though fairly, your tool should do that itself.

As I stated above, you probably have hand-crafted bundles if you need to resort to this solution. Consider using a tool like [bndtools](http://bndtools.org/) to build your bundles for you.